# RISC-V: How do you store specific values in large addresses in Venus (RISC-V sim)?

Tags: risc-v

I'm new to RISC-V and I'm having trouble understanding how one would store specific values in large addresses. For example, if I wanted to store the value 5 in 0x12312312, how would you go about that?

Comment: using store statement in RISC-V ISA of course.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The largest value you can make a register via the addi instruction is 2047. Addresses in RISC-V are 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires two steps. "Load upper immediate":

[image]

and add the 12 LSBits:

[image]

*Images source: "The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume I: Unprivileged ISA"*

Example to build any constant/address: a5 = 0x12345678

```
lui a5,0x12345000(305418240)
addi a5,a5,1656
```

For values with all 12 LSbits = 0, only `lui` is required. For small values, `addi` to register 0 is enough.

Another example: add 65535 to a pointer stored at address (a3):

```
   lw   a5,0(a3)  -> load the base address, stored in (a3) to a5
   lui  a4,0x10   -> "build" the initial MSBit of the constant
   addi a4,a4,-1 # ffff -> "build" the final value of the constant
   add  a5,a5,a4  -> calculate the new adress
   sw   a5,0(a3)  -> store the new address
```

Comment: This clears stuff up. I guess if you're in a situation where you need to add more than 2047 to an address, you just use the addi instruction twice?

Comment: I've added another example. It gets simpler for small values, as you mentioned, and also with shifts with all 12 the LSBits equal 0.